# Making two equations left-aligned

Tags: equations

I'm trying to use a single label for two equations. I use this:

```
\begin{equation} 
\begin{aligned}    
T_{Up} = \max \{T_{Up\_min}, u\}  \\
T_{Low} = \min \{T_{Low\_min}, l \}
\label{Eq2}
\end{aligned}  
\end{equation}
```

The problem is that these two equations are now center-aligned. How can I make them left-aligned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recommended version: they are neither centered, nor left-aligned, nor right-aligned. The equal signs are aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
T_\mathrm{Up} &= \max \{T_{\mathrm{Up}\_\min}, u\}  \\
T_\mathrm{Low} &= \min \{T_{\mathrm{Low}\_\min}, l \}
\label{Eq2}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want them to be *strictly* left aligned, then (but please don't do this! Your readers will be grateful).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&T_\mathrm{Up} = \max \{T_{\mathrm{Up}\_\min}, u\}  \\
&T_\mathrm{Low} = \min \{T_{\mathrm{Low}\_\min}, l \}
\label{Eq2}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but my question is that since *T_Up_min* is the name of a variable, why should we write it like *T_{\mathrm{Up}\_\min}*? I mean isn't *\min* used for declaring "min function"?

Comment: @helen Is it *U* x *p* x *m* x *i* x *n*? If not, you have to use roman font for both. That is somewhat a mathematical writing law

Comment: @helen If you want then you can also use `\mathrm{min}` -- it depends on the content. In its current state I understand that this is the minimum value of Up, hence `\min`.

Comment: yes, it's the minimum value of the T_Up.

Comment: @helen So `\min`. Or `\mathrm{min}`.

Comment: Thanks. Does this rule apply to other subscripts as well? I mean for example if the second parameter of max (I mean *u*) has a subscript like *Average*, should I write it like *u_\mathrm{Average}*?

Comment: @helen Yes. If you write "Average" in italic, I will understand it as the product of seven variables: *A*, *v*, *e*, *r*, *a*, *g* and *e*.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are searching for the option `fleqn`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
T_\mathrm{Up} &= \max \{T_{\mathrm{Up}\_\min}, u\}  \\
T_\mathrm{Low} &= \min \{T_{\mathrm{Low}\_\min}, l \}
\label{Eq2}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```